# Grouping / expanding rows with common data

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I am retrieving data from a mysql database with a basic Select query (SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE customer_name = xxxxxxx). This is then displayed in a table / form as the user requires the ability to do something with the result.

I've formatted a table in css using classes to define the width, background, text alignment etc, and am using a foreach loop to pass the output from the query to the browser to display it.

All fairly straight forward so far.

My question is whether it is possible to group rows containing a common data element together and expand them on hover over or with a mouse press? For example, if I have multiple occurrences of rows with the same customer name, can I group those together? Next week, there may not be multiples so it all needs to be dynamically read.

I don't know where to start, or even what terms to search for to extend my knowledge and because the data changes daily, I am working on the assumption that the data may need to be queried first and formatted / displayed to the user as a batch. To this end I have considered that passing the query result using a foreach loop may no longer be the most appropriate means of presenting the retrieved data to the user despite having served me well. I also don't know of another way to accomplish this which doesn't help :)

My table is currently structured as follows:-

```
<tr>
<td class="standard">ID</td>
<td class="standard">Customer Name</td>
<td class="standard">Customer Tel</td>
<td class="standard">Requirement</td>
</tr>

foreach ($sql as $row) {
echo '<tr>
<td class="standard">'.$row->id.'</td>
<td class="standard">'.$row->customer_name.'</td>
<td class="standard">'.$row->customer_tel.'</td>
<td class="standard">'.$row->requirement.'</td>
</tr>';
}
```

Any pointers would be gratefully received.

Many thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you culd just group them in your SQL query. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE customer_name = xxxxxxx GROUP BY customer_name
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE customer_name = xxxxxxx ORDER BY customer_name
```

Then when you are creating the rows on the front end they will already be next to each other. You will need to use a jQuery click function to expand the rows if you want to show/hide data. When you click to expand to show the data with your jQuery click function you can expand based on $row->customer_name value.

Comment: @Jonn - It's the jQuery pointer that I think is the missing link for me, thank you. I had thought about the group by, but need the list ordered by another field, however there's nothing to stop me from ordering by date and customer name as the multiples will all be required on the same day. Fabulous, thank you. I'll post what I come up with......

Comment: that's another thought, although the missing link for me is knowing how to relate the contents of the cell to the div or row. Presumably I can create some script that looks at the $row->customer_name value and formats depending on the answer?

Comment: Honestly i would build it with div's. `<div class="row"><div class="column-1"></div></div>` Then you can use jQuery to select rows based on the name in column-1. Use a click function so when they click to expand a row, you grab the name in column-2 `var customerName = $('.column-2').text();` Then loop through all rows and if you find a name that matches that customerName then show that row as well.

Comment: I use jQuery for most of this type of stuff - it honestly doesn't take long to learn and its really powerfull - only been using jquery for about 6 months. Just hit up their API at jQuery.com

Comment: thank you, it's useful to know that it isn't a big leap to learn. I'm (relatively) new to php / css / mysql and have reached a crossroads with my knowledge where I want to do things like the above. Half the battle is knowing the terms to search for to find information, so the pointers you have given above are actually massively helpful as it gives me somewhere to start. I hadn't thought creating variables from the query results. Obvioius when one knows :) Thanks again.